# How to extract AWS EC2 instances with their corresponding Sec Groups and Source info?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to extract all of our EC2 instances, but I want to know how can I include Sec Groups, and Source Info.

EC2 Instance | Security Group | source Info that has (0.0.0.0/0)

Answer (score 1):

You would start by calling `DescribeInstances()`, since that will return a list of Amazon EC2 instances and their associated Security Groups.

Then, for each of the returned Security Groups, you would then call `DescribeSecurityGroups()` for that group to obtain the `IpPermissions`, which describe the Inbound rules.

For example:

```json
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "IpRanges": [],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "UserId": "123456789012",
                            "GroupId": "sg-903004f8"
                        }
                    ],
                    "PrefixListIds": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "Description": "Access from NY office",
                            "CidrIp": "203.0.113.0/24"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": []
                    }
            ],
```

This is saying that Port 22 inbound access is permitted from `203.0.113.0/24`.